# Configuring DNS for new web host while keeping old mail server

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cname-record, a-record

I would very much appreciate your advice on the proper way to configure our DNS to move our website **only** from our current all-in-one provider to Bluehost.

Our DNS is managed at Network Solutions. We are keeping our mail at the current host.

Current DNS looks like this:

```
A RECORDS: 
www                       123.456.78.9 
@(None)                   123.456.78.9 
*(All Others)             123.456.78.9 

MX: 
ourcompanyname.com        mx.currenthostname.com. (priority 10)

CNAME: 
mail.ourcompanyname.com   mail.currenthostname.com.
```

I did not set this up. I know I need to change the A records to the IP addresses of bluehost's nameserver(s). But I have a few questions:

- How do I incorporate the IP for the failback nameserver?
- Is there an A record missing for mail? Is the * record handling mail right now?

I have received different answers from different customer service reps and now I'm confused.

Thank you **very** much.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you need to REMOVE the wildcard DNS and just manually enter all of your subdomains *minus* as you mentioned the mail. one. Which that will need to point to the current mail server as you mentioned.

From there you should be set.

**I would however STRONGLY consider a non EIG provider though. There are many SMBs within that price that can likely give you better web service, customer service, etc.**